# What does undefined : fmt.Println(build) means in GOlang? while using "fmt.Println(len("hello world")"

Tags: go

[image]

I am new to go language and programming.

Can anyone explain what does the error means and how can I tackle it?

Comment: It's fmt.Println and not fmt.PrintLn

Comment: @T.Claverie Thank you, that got my program running. But still, can you explain what undefined means in go language? I don't really get the concept

Comment: As its name suggest, something that is undefined is something that has not been defined before. In programming, you will only manipulate things that have been defined previously. Wether they are variables, functions, types, anything. Usually, when the error is that something is 'undefined' it means you have a typo in a function/variable. In order to get used to programming ang to the Go language, I advise you to take the Tour of Go (https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to have your first steps in this world. This tutorial is very accessible and covers lots of important concepts.

Comment: @T.Claverie Thank you that was very helpful. i'll sure see to the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 12):

Use `fmt.Println` instead of `fmt.PrintLn`. Make letter L lowercase.

Comment: thank you sir. But still, can you explain the concept of undefined in go language?

Comment: In this case, "undefined" implies that the `fmt` package doesn't *define* the `PrintLn` function. In other words, the entire call to `fmt.PrintLn()` is *undefined*. If you were able to update the `fmt` package to include a complete function for `PrintLn`, it would then be *defined*.